# Finding Sync of Columns in R

Tags: r

Data

```
    v1 <- c(52.9799999999814, 53.4200000000128, 52.0899999999965, 57.9700000000012, 
    60.679999999993, 0.300000000017462, 1.76999999998952, 61.1900000000023, 
    58.9599999999919, 1.73000000001048, 0.269999999989523, 6.92000000001281, 
    60.5299999999988, 60.859999999986, 59.5599999999977, 61.0600000000268, 
    60.6299999999756, 60.9700000000012, 60.1600000000035, 60.4599999999919, 
    60.0900000000256)

    v2 <- c(52.679999999993, 53.140000000014, 52.8899999999849, 57.6700000000128, 
    60.5199999999895, 2.04000000000815, 61.890000000014, 59.5699999999779, 
    2.05999999999767, 6.98000000001048, 60.7399999999907, 60.7799999999988, 
    59.7300000000105, 60.9100000000035, 60.3299999999872, 60.5500000000175, 
    60.6600000000035, 60.3499999999767, 60.7300000000105, 60.6700000000128, 
    60.3799999999756)

tv3 <- data.frame(v1,v2)


    tv3$v5 <- tv3$v2 - tv3$v1
    tv3$v5
     [1]  -0.30  -0.28   0.80  -0.30  -0.16   1.74  60.12  -1.62 -56.90   5.25  60.47  53.86  -0.80
    [14]   0.05   0.77  -0.51   0.03  -0.62   0.57   0.21   0.29
```

So you see, the difference should remain smaller, if it is larger, like in this case, at particular row, it gets 60.

So basically if we remove the 0.30 row in just V1 and shift it one cell up, The difference wouldn't hike upto 60. 
So the 0.30 is noise value and that's what I have to figure and put it in V3

My desired results are the following.

```
    v1       v2     V3
    52.98   52.68   0.3
    53.42   53.14   0.27
    52.09   52.89   
    57.97   57.67   
    60.68   60.52   
    1.77    2.04    
    61.19   61.89   
    58.96   59.57   
    1.73    2.06    
    6.92    6.98    
    60.53   60.74   
    60.86   60.78   
    59.56   59.73   
    61.06   60.91   
    60.63   60.33   
    60.97   60.55   
    60.16   60.66   
    60.46   60.35   
    60.09   60.73
```

So notice here that all the sequence of columns seem to be in sync with just a difference of few points.

May be my case requires implementation of Needleman-Wunsch Algo

Comment: What does `v2` have to do with this? What do you mean by "indices", do you mean "values"? Can you show your desired result? Are you trying to just remove outliers, does the order have anything to do with it? Or just anything that's not close to, say, the median, you want removed?

Comment: @Gregor I have updated the question.

Comment: how did you get `v3`?

Comment: @Sotos I got it from V1, There's a value 0.30 and 0.27. So I removed the row in V1 containing 0.30 and 0.27

Comment: so you want to remove all rows where the value of `v1` is less than something? Why just 0.3 and 0.27 removed? Are those values exceeding some threshold? We need to understand the logic in order to help you.

Comment: @sotos I have edited the question, might answer your question. I have to pick up certain noise values which when comes up in V1, the order of sync of two columns get disturbed or another way to put it is that the difference of both columns get abruptly high values